# topbeat to monitor specific java process

Tags: topbeat

I am newbie to the beats. I am using topbeat to monitor the system health.
Up to this point everything is fine.

Now I need to monitor the resource utilization of a java process, so I configured `topbeat.yml` as: `procs: ["java"]`

In my linux box there are 4 java processes are running but I am interested in only one java process. So,

1. Is there any way to monitor specific java process using regex?
2. Is there any way to differentiate the processes by name [not with pid]?

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to view certain processes then you can use sample topbeat dashboards and in that dashboard there is one search which is for proc stats. From there select proc.name from the available fields and further filter it to select your relevant proc.name
Suggestion from elastic forum: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/topbeat-monitor-specific-java-process/65594/2 Try MetricBeat and see if it helps.

Comment: `proc.name` is always java as I set `procs: ["java"]` in yml. I want to understand is there any other way, kind of regex, to watch specific process (i.e. one of the java process out of 4)

Comment: then add proc.commandline and you should be able to see full process command then in kibana just filter based on the proc.commandline

Comment: By the way in topbeat.yml keep procs: [".*"], I am asking you to look into Kibana and then create a dashboard from there. I assume you have installed sample dashboards in kibana for topbeat

Comment: I am checking these stats in graphite browser as I am redirecting the matrix to the graphite. However `procs: [".*"]` means all the processes - which i am not interested in. Also it will simple increase the load on the topbeat as there are thousands of processes are running in the linux box

Comment: There are kibana default dashboards available with topbeat..which can be tried and they also give you all the information necessary. as far as capturing all the process info is concerned it is upto you to select all or few. Also did you had a look at this post: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-to-log-additional-data-for-a-given-process-such-as-command-line/39702